# How to create a plot with stacked and labeled line segments

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to create sort of Stacked Bar Chart [don't know the proper name]. I hand drew the graph [for years 2016 and 2017] and attached it here.

[image]

The code to create the df is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = [[2016.0, 0.4862, 0.4115, 0.3905, 0.3483, 0.1196],
 [2017.0, 0.4471, 0.4096, 0.3725, 0.2866, 0.1387],
 [2018.0, 0.4748, 0.4016, 0.3381, 0.2905, 0.2012],
 [2019.0, 0.4705, 0.4247, 0.3857, 0.3333, 0.2457],
 [2020.0, 0.4755, 0.4196, 0.3971, 0.3825, 0.2965]]

cols = ['attribute_time', '100-81 percentile', '80-61 percentile', '60-41 percentile', '40-21 percentile', '20-0 percentile']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
#set seaborn plotting aesthetics
sns.set(style='white')
#create stacked bar chart
df.set_index('attribute_time').plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

The data doesn't need to stack on top of each other. The code will create a stacked bar chart, but that's not exactly what needs to be displayed. The percentile needs to have labeled horizontal lines indicating the percentile on the x axis for that year. Does anyone have recommendations on how to achieve this goal? Is it a sort of modified stacked bar chart that needs to be visualized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My approach to this is to represent the data as a categorical scatter plot (stripplot in Seaborn) using horizontal lines rather than points as markers.  You'll have to make some choices about exactly how and where you want to plot things, but this should get you started!

I first modified the data a little bit:

```
df['attribute_time'] = df['attribute_time'].astype('int') # Just to get rid of the decimals.

df = df.melt(id_vars = ['attribute_time'],
    value_name = 'pct_value',
    var_name = 'pct_range')
```

Melting the DataFrame takes the wide data and makes it long instead, so the columns are now `year`, `pct_value`, and `pct_range` and there is a row for each data point.

Next is the plotting:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sns.stripplot(data = df,
    x = 'attribute_time',
    y = 'pct_value',
    hue = 'pct_range',
    jitter = False,
    marker = '_',
    s = 40,
    linewidth = 3,
    ax = ax)
```

Instead of labeling each point with the range that it belongs to, I though it would be a lot cleaner to separate them into ranges by color.

The `jitter` is used when there are lots of points for a given category that might overlap to try and prevent them from touching.  In this case, we don't need to worry about that so I turned the jitter off. The `marker` style is [designated here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/markers_api.html) as `hline`.

The `s` parameter is the horizontal width of each line, and the `linewidth` is the thickness, so you can play around with those a bit to see what works best for you.

Text is added to the figure using the `ax.text` method as follows:

```
for year, value in zip(df['attribute_time'],df['pct_value']):
    ax.text(year - 2016,
        value,
        str(value),
        ha = 'center',
        va = 'bottom',
        fontsize = 'small')
```

The figure coordinates are indexed starting from 0 despite the horizontal markers displaying the years, so the x position of the text is shifted left by the minimum year (2016).  The y position is equal to the value, and the text itself is a string representation of the value.  The text is centered above the line and sits slightly above it due to the vertical anchor being on the bottom.
[image: categorical scatter plot with horizontal line markers]
There's obviously a lot you can tweak to make it look how you want with sizing and labeling and stuff, but hopefully this is at least a good start!